# Which word is correct in this sentence? (signing/signature)

Tags: grammar, word-formation

Consider the following:

> The financial industry got its (22) ________ (office) start on Wall Street on May 17, 1792. On that day, New York's first stock exchange was established by the (23) ________ **(sign)** of the Buttonwood Agreement.'
>   <sub>www.livescience.com ([Link](https://docplayer.hu/53624340-Erettsegi-vizsga-majus-11-angol-nyelv-kozepszintu-irasbeli-vizsga-majus-11-8-00-i-olvasott-szoveg-ertese-idotartam-60-perc.html))</sub>

*(from the Hungarian School Leaving Exam (MATURA), May 2017)*

The task was to write the correct word formed from the word in the parentheses. The instructions were as follows

> You are going to read an article about the origins of the name of *Wall Street*. Some words are missing from the text.
>
> - Use the words in brackets to form the words that fit in the gaps (18-25).
> - Then write the appropriate form of these words on the dotted lines after the text.
> - There might be cases when you do not have to change the word in brackets.
> - Use only one word for each gap.

Naturally, we have two options for (23). Either it's **signature** or it's **signing**.

Which one is correct? Are both correct?

According to the online Oxford Dictionary, *signature* can be used as a *mass noun*, with the meaning of *'the action of signing a document.'*

Comment: If you google "the signature of", none of the first 30 ... examples given involve the 'actual signing on the dotted line' sense. As is often the case, the noun-orientated ing-form specifies the act [here of signing] whereas the noun specifies the result etc. But you fail to mention any research you yourself have done (does a reasonable dictionary list these words as synonyms?) // Actually, M-W does. The question now is "Is it _better_ to reserve the use 'signature' for the result, not the act?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There, I updated my question for you. As you already mentioned, M-W lists these words, and also Oxford Dictionary *does* include this meaning of the word. Is this enough to conclude that *signaure* is **correct** in the sentence? Regardless whether it's better or worse than *signing*.

Comment: (1) 'Signature' is not a verb-form, so the question doesn't arise here ('write the correct form of the verb'). I skip-read here; I assumed the  question was asking for the correct member of the family. // (2) It's not 'incorrect' to call a spade an agricultural implement. But don't 'better' and 'worse' overlap with 'correctness'? If the constraint in (1) is removed, could a decent English teacher knock a mark off for a totally unacceptable usage if you choose to use 'signature' rather than 'signing' here? _No_. Might they deduct a mark for style? ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (1) You are quite right, *singature* is not a verb-form. I fixed that in the body of the question. \\
(2) I agree, they do overlap. However, the aim of my question was purely to find out whether I have a reason to complain in case I lose a mark for *sigature*. I understand that *signing* is stylistically better. \\
(3) I might be wrong, but I feel a tiny bit of hostility against me in your comments. Actually, English is not my native language and I am still far from perfecting it. I am trying to *learn*.

Comment: 'But you fail to mention any research you yourself have done (does a reasonable dictionary list these words as synonyms?)': ELU (and not myself; I just try to do my bit to preserve site respectability / integrity: you're not 'updating your question for [me]') expects reasonable research to be shown. This is made plain at the Help Center. // "Is this correct?" questions often make the assumption that there are no areas where there is disagreement among native speakers. You would certainly not lose a mark for using 'signing' here.  You might or might not for using 'signature'. I'd never ...

Comment: choose an answer I considered unfamiliar over one I knew to be totally acceptable. However, in your case, one needs to know how the examiners rate 'idiomaticity' (how commonly a usage is used by proficient users) as opposed to 'has any dictionary found evidence of this usage?' And only they can answer that. Quirk and Svartvik proposed the existence of a gradience of acceptability for grammatical constructions (rather than a right / wrong dichotomy), and the same complications are apparent when it comes to judging what is le mot juste.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, that's all right. What is considered enough research? I checked in dictionaries, which listed *signature* as *the act of signing*. I could not find, however, examples of using the word in this way. I thought that it was fine to ask the question, as native speakers can obviously bring up examples, since they are familiar with much more sources and texts. Perhaps that idea was wrong, excuse me.
Nonetheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: "According to the online Oxford Dictionary, _signature_ can be used as a mass noun, with the meaning of 'the action of signing a document.' " is sufficient. You can show this as evidence to authorities. But they remain authorities; they have the final say in matters like this. As I said, I'd have played safe with 'signing'. Using 'signature' here might not be ungrammatical, but it certainly sounds odd to my ears. And that hints quite strongly at it being an unidiomatic usage. And unidiomaticity can be as unacceptable as ungrammaticality.

Comment: I think a difficultly with *signature* is that it does not come from the verb *sign*. So perhaps the testmakers were simply testing your ability to form a *ing* form....

Comment: @Clare I disagree. The word *signature* does come from the verb *sign*, in the following construction: *sign(a)*-*ture*. In the same way temperature once meant "the state of being tempered", formed from the verb *temper* using the construction: *temper(a)*-*ture*. Ultimately, it is derived from Latin, but is not non-existent in English. That said, as Edwin pointed out, *signing* is a lot more idiomatic in this case, and thus is likely to be considered the correct answer.

Comment: *Signature* doesn't come from *sign*, nor does *temperature* come from *temper*.  *Signature* comes from either French or Latin, and *temperature* comes from Latin.  Ultimately, *sign* is from the same Latin root as *signature*, and *temper* from the same Latin root as *temperature*, though.

Comment: The most common meaning (though not the only meaning) of "signature" is a person's name, written by that person, to indicate agreement with some document. The most common meaning of "signing" is the action of writing such a signature. The latter is what is relevant in the example sentence, so I'd prefer "signing".

Comment: //....by the (23) ________ (sign) of the Buttonwood Agreement.....//  By the signing of the Buttonwood Agreement sounds more flowing than ...by the signature of.... It could be a matter of ease and fluency, rather than what is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Either word is correct here, but 'signing' would be the more commonly used word.

Signature is more commonly used to refer to the product of signing one's name than the act of signing itself. It is defined by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/signature) as

> 1. A person's name, written by that person, used as identification or to
>      signify approval of accompanying material, such as a legal contract.
> 2. An act of signing one's name; an act of producing a signature.

The [Cambridge Dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/signature) for Signature meaning the

> the act of signing something

notes it as formal. It would still be correct to use it in this instance, but it is a less common usage.

To provide some evidence of this usage of signature being less common than signing, I did some Google searches.

A Google search for "signature of the Magna Carta" provides about 15,500 results while "signing of the Magna Carta" provides about 99,200. Below is a table with results for the same Google searches with some other historical documents.

```
Document that was signed        Signature    Signing
Magna Carta                     15,500       99,200
Declaration of Independence     186,000      713,000
Treaty of Paris                 81,000       236,000
Treaty of Versailles            41,600       168,000
Buttonwood Agreement            4            1,850
```

As you can see, signing is much more common than signature in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

I can somewhat understand either. But I lean more toward "signing of" because if you read the latter part of the sentence the insertion if "signature" seems awkward.

'the signature of the Buttonwood Agreement.'

Answer (score 0):

"Signing of" will be perfect in your sentence. Its an agreement which would be signed by many. 'On that day, New York's first stock exchange was established by the **signing of** the Buttonwood Agreement'

Whereas use "Signature" would mean that unless someone actually signed in, the stock exchange would not have started.

'On that day, New York's first stock exchange was established by the **signature** of Mr. Someone.'

Comment: Your answer may well be correct, but how is anyone to tell? At SE EL&U we're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).